# Creating gpa variable using mutate and pivot_longer

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to make a GPA variable which is just the average of students' grades. The problem is that some students haven't taken all four classes, so I can't just sum these up and divide by 4.

For the data below, 1 = A, 2 = B, 3 = C, 4 = D or lower. Anything 5 or higher should be discarded or effectively be counted as an NA. Also, I'd first want to recode the letter grades so that 4 = A, 3 = B, 3 = C, 1 = D or lower (which I'd just do with mutate).

I first tried with pivot_longer but I was struggling to handle the missing/irrelevant values and also seemed very inefficient. What is the best way to get the individual GPA for each student?

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 
12, 13, 14, 15), grade_eng = c(98, 3, 
3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4), grade_math = c(5, 4, 
3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4), grade_hist = c(3, 3, 
4, 6, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4), grade_sci = c(3, 2, 4, 
3, 6, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 2, 97, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `pivot_longer()` to get the data into a tidier form. Then, you can use some of the functions from the `dplyr` package to do what you want. The nice thing about these functions is that they are intuitive about what they do. Note, I do not recode your numeric grade data to letters because that data is being aggregated when calculating GPA.

```
library(tidyverse)

gpa_df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("grade"), names_to = "course", values_to = "grade") %>%
  filter(grade <= 4) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(gpa = mean(grade))

# A tibble: 15 x 2
      ID   gpa
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  3   
 2     2  3   
 3     3  3.5 
 4     4  2.67
 5     5  2.67
 6     6  1.25
 7     7  1.25
 8     8  2.75
 9     9  1   
10    10  2.5 
11    11  3.33
12    12  1.5 
13    13  2   
14    14  1.5 
15    15  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a typo and meant for row 11 to be `ID` 11 and not 1:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("grade"), ~ fct_rev(LETTERS[replace(., . > 4, NA)]))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(GPA = mean(as.numeric(c_across(starts_with("grade"))), na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

1. First we replace irrelevant values with `NA` by using `replace(., . > 4, NA)`.
2. `LETTERS` is a base `R` vector, where `LETTERS[1]` returns `"A"` and so forth.
3. `forcats::fct_rev` turns the values into factors in reverse alphabetical order. So "D" is the first factor, "C" is the second, and so on.
4. Then across the rows (assuming each row is a separate `ID`) we compute the mean, excluding `NA`.

**Output**

```
      ID grade_eng grade_math grade_hist grade_sci   GPA
   <dbl> <fct>     <fct>      <fct>      <fct>     <dbl>
 1     1 NA        NA         C          C          2   
 2     2 C         D          C          B          2   
 3     3 C         C          D          D          1.5 
 4     4 B         C          NA         C          2.33
 5     5 C         C          B          NA         2.33
 6     6 A         A          A          B          3.75
 7     7 A         A          B          A          3.75
 8     8 C         C          C          B          2.25
 9     9 A         A          A          A          4   
10    10 B         NA         NA         C          2.5 
11     1 D         D          B          NA         1.67
12    12 A         B          A          B          3.5 
13    13 B         C          A          NA         3   
14    14 A         B          A          B          3.5 
15    15 D         D          D          D          1
```